# Magento 2 - Add meta detail on frontend page using Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, meta-tags

I have `custom block` in my custom module, which call my frontend `custom phtml` file.

let's say file path: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Index\Index.php`

I need to figure out the way to set `meta title`, `meta keywords` and `meta description` using `Block`

I already set the page title by using following code in Block

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{

        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My page title'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Comment: Why you want use only Block?

Comment: Because I already set the page title through block, so I think there might be the way to set meta tags using block as well. if not tell me other way in answer but it should not use any extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Get exact idea how to set **page meta data** via block refer `vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Page.php`

In this magento have a function

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    // ...
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Custom Page title'));
    $this->pageConfig->setKeywords(__('Custom Page keywords'));
    $this->pageConfig->setDescription(__('Custom Page description'));

    // ...
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

so in other word i can say like use  `$this->pageConfig->setKeywords` and `$this->pageConfig->setDescription` respectively to set meta keyword and meta description.

Hope you will get your expected output.

Comment: let me try this, come back to you

Comment: @MuhammadHasham let us know the feedback, happy to help you.

Comment: Great It worked, Thanks :) I know it can be done through block and you got it right.